# Hostname does not match the server certificate - using old expired certificate

Tags: ruby, sockets, ssl, websocket, openssl

I am trying to connect via TCP socket to an old, unmaintained game server. When I try to do so using OpenSSL and Socketry, I get following error.

> hostname "xxx" does not match the server certificate

This is how my code works.

```
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
ssl_context.ciphers = "AES128-SHA"
ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("certificate.crt"))
ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("certificate.key"))

socket = Socketry::SSL::Socket.new(ssl_context: ssl_context)
socket.connect(address, port)
```

I've had to force cipher to AES128-SHA, as otherwise I would get a different error.

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: dh key too small (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

How can I bypass these errors and just force connection to said server? The certificate itself has expired 10 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Socketry](https://github.com/socketry/socketry) doesn't include much documentation about this, so you need to turn to the source. Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you might try one of the following:

1. Passing `verify_hostname: false` to [Socket#connect](https://github.com/socketry/socketry/blob/master/lib/socketry/ssl/socket.rb#L77).
2. Rescuing [Socketry::SSL::HostnameError](https://github.com/socketry/socketry/blob/master/lib/socketry/ssl/socket.rb#L85) yourself.
3. Rescuing [Socketry::SSL::CertificateVerifyError](https://github.com/socketry/socketry/blob/master/lib/socketry/exceptions.rb#L41).

At least one of these ought to address your specific issue. If not, the source offers other places you might monkey-patch or refine for your use case.

Comment: Thank you! I started looking at source code, but somehow I missed that verify_hostname thing, it solved the issue :)